# Detect route change in react-router-native

Tags: react-native, react-router-native

I'm using react-router-native to navigate between the "pages" of my app. The problem here is that I want to change the app-bar visibility depending on the user location.
So, I need a way to watch and detect the route, so I can manipulate-it

Comment: React router is mainly used on react and not react native. You might want to add the tag "react" to your post

Comment: Are you building website or mobile app using React Native?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

To solve the problem I created a callback function inside my components, that returns whenever it loads. So with that I could just check a variable like
`isAtLogin ? (<Appbar />) : (<View />)` to show and hide the appbar.